# Do Samsung wireless chargers work with Lumia phones?

Tags: charging

I need to buy a wireless charger and most of the ones I can find in stores are from Samsung and their description doesn't say "Qi". Are they working with Windows phones like Lumia 930?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine had a Samsung Wireless Charger for his Galaxy S7 - I successfully used it with my Lumia 950 XL.

I'd suggest trying it in-store to be certain.  Or, find a store that will allow you to return it if it doesn't work.

Comment: I've a Samsung "Charging Pad" that works with my Lumia 930.